# how to know which 3D API an application uses?

Tags: opengl, directx

If I was given an arbitrary 3D application, say a screensaver, or a game, how can I know which DirectX or OpenGL version it is using during runtime?  Assuming I have no information about the binary to be google online, like say somebody just wrote a DirectX demo and give it to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some additional tools like: [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and chect what DLL's are used by the app.

If you have OpenGL app then you can use [gDebugger](http://developer.amd.com/tools/gDEBugger/Pages/default.aspx) to investgate what function calls are invoked and in which order. Similarly for DX app there is a PIX

Comment: Thanks, actually I did think of DependencyWalker, but if an application links to both OpenGL and Direct3D (9,10,11) at the same time, then all the DLL would be linked right?

Comment: I am aware of gDebugger and APITrace for OpenGL, I'm wondering if there are others that also do Direct3D 10 and 11? Other than PIX, cause it doesn't seem to work on many the 3D applications I try.

Comment: There is NVidia Perf Hud and "GPU PerfStudio" from AMD, but I have no experience with them recently.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a Windows machine you can use Process Explorer (PE).

1. Launch PE. Press CTRL + L or View -> tick "Show Lower Pane"
2. Launch your application.
3. Find your application among those in PE. You will be able to see all the dynamic libraries used in the lower pane. If you can't see anything in the lower pane run process explorer with administrator privileges.

PE is very detailed on this. You will most likely find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the program binary will link to either the Direct3D DLL or the OpenGL DLL. In DirectX each version has a own set of DLLs. In the case of OpenGL the only way to tell is to intercept OpenGL calls. OpenGL-3 and beyond require some special context creation method, which includes setting the expected version. Anything before OpenGL-3 is actually OpenGL-1.1 with extensions, where some of the extensions became core functionality.